# Why would my API App swagger be unavailable to my Azure App Service Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-apps

I have created a simple api with a test controller and published it as an Azure Api App. I have public (anonymous) access enabled, the swagger ui works well in the browser and the swagger validates correctly, and I have added to it the default response setting that Logic Apps require.

When I try to add the Api App to my Logic App, however, I encounter a fault: "Error fetching swagger api definition".

If I try to browse the API definition in the portal I encounter another fault "Cannot get the API definition. It may require additional configuration or authentication on the API app."

If I try to download the swagger data from the portal link this fails with `Http 400: Bad Request`.

What am I missing here and how do I get this simple Api App working in the portal?

Public URI: https://microsoft-apiappf6c70a179b1b408c99e3f2536467ff39.azurewebsites.net

Swagger UI: https://microsoft-apiappf6c70a179b1b408c99e3f2536467ff39.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Raw Swagger:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"PE.Services.Idml"},"host":"microsoft-apiappf6c70a179b1b408c99e3f2536467ff39.azurewebsites.net:443","schemes":["https"],"paths":{"/api/ToEpl":{"get":{"tags":["ToEpl"],"operationId":"ToEpl_Get","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}},"default":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}}},"deprecated":false},"post":{"tags":["ToEpl"],"operationId":"ToEpl_Post","consumes":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"value","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"type":"string"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Object"}},"default":{"description":"OK","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Object"}}},"deprecated":false}},"/api/ToEpl/{id}":{"get":{"tags":["ToEpl"],"operationId":"ToEpl_Get","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"string"}},"default":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"string"}}},"deprecated":false},"put":{"tags":["ToEpl"],"operationId":"ToEpl_Put","consumes":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"value","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"type":"string"}}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}},"deprecated":false},"delete":{"tags":["ToEpl"],"operationId":"ToEpl_Delete","consumes":[],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}},"deprecated":false}},"/api/Values":{"get":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Get","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}},"default":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}}},"deprecated":false},"post":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Post","consumes":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"value","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"type":"string"}}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}},"deprecated":false}},"/api/Values/{id}":{"get":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_GetById","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"string"}},"default":{"description":"OK","schema":{"type":"string"}}},"deprecated":false},"put":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Put","consumes":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"},{"name":"value","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"type":"string"}}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}},"deprecated":false},"delete":{"tags":["Values"],"operationId":"Values_Delete","consumes":[],"produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}],"responses":{"204":{"description":"No Content"}},"deprecated":false}}},"definitions":{"Object":{"type":"object","properties":{}}}}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem... have you figured anything out? I'm trying to figure it out myself... have no idea what I changed to make this stop working, all I pass around are POCO's.

Comment: @Scott No. We've come to the conclusion that for the moment Logic Apps are not quite ready for production. We'll use Api Apps and traditional WF to connect them and wait for documentation and some additional workflow features to catch up in Logic Apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you have two routes with the same operationId (ToEpl_Get).

There are a few mitigations

1. Since Swashbuckle derives this from the action name in your api controller…you can change one of your action names…e.g. GetById instead of Get
2. Alternatively, the way to change operation id is to go to the SwaggerConfig.cs file add add a custom operation filter. The operation filter extension point will give you access to the operation and to change the id.

So sorry for the inconvenience, and we will be making our error reporting better soon.